# how to colour the group in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am very new to SSRS.
There is an SSRS report of the  below format.The requirement is to colour the group.I mean Denmark has to be in one colour,Uk in another colour and France in different colour.
what expression is required to achieve this?

```
Country    Ppl1  Ppl2   year

Denamrk   1320   2321   2000
Denamrk   150   261   2001
Denamrk   610   821   2002
Denamrk   6510   2541   2003
Uk        230   14321  2000
Uk        2340   1421  2001
Uk        34520   1621  2002
Uk        2670   1271  2003
France     3312   1243   2000
France     3512   6123   2001
France     3312   1523   2002
France     31212   1523   2003
```

required result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example is based on a table report item to display you information.

1. Select the detail row in the table
2. In the Properties click on "BackgroundColor" drop box and click on Expression link
3. Use IIF function to change color

Example expression ..

```
=IIf(Fields!Country.Value = "Denmark", "Green", IIf(Fields!Country.Value = "UK", "Red", IIf(Fields!Country.Value = "UK", "Orange", "Transparent")))
```

Sorry do not have points to post picture.